# InteliJ, the marks of local changes next to the line numbers are gone

Tags: intellij-idea

In InteliJ editor on the sidebar where the line numbers are, there used to be indication for changes I made in the file and not commited yet.

Then I could press it and reset.

Not talking about the "Annotation" feature.

It should be where the red mark is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to the **Settings/Preferences** dialog, select **Editor | General** on the left, and check the **Highlight modified lines in gutter** option.